# Convolution and laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

I was wondering why using convolution gives a different result:

Find the Laplace transformation of $e^t\sin t$.

Using convolution :

$1/s-1 *1/s^2-1$

using table:
$1/(s-1)^2-1$

Comment: $L(\sin t)=\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}$.

Comment: $L(e^tsint)\neq L(e^t)L(\sin t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using convolution, for $f(t) = e^{t},~ g(t) = \sin t$, we have

$$(f * g)(t) = \displaystyle \int_0^t e^{\tau} ~\sin(t - \tau)~d \tau = \dfrac{1}{2}(e^{t} + \sin t - \cos t)$$

Calculate the Laplace Transform of that convolution result.

Next, note that (compare to the previous result)

$$\mathcal{L}(f * g) = \mathcal{L}(f)~\mathcal{L}(g) = F(s)~G(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} ~ \frac{1}{s^2+1}$$

**Update**

Lastly

$$\mathcal{L} (e^t \sin t) = \dfrac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}$$

We derive this using entirely different methods than above, for example, using the definition of the Laplace Transform, we have

$$\mathcal{L}(e^t \sin t) = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} e^{-s t} f(t) dt = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-s t} (e^t \sin t)~dt = \dfrac{1}{s^2-2 s+2}$$

We can also use item $19.$ from the [*Laplace Table*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf), we have

$$\mathcal{L} (e^{at} \sin (b t)) = \dfrac{b}{(s-a)^2 + b^2 } = \dfrac {1}{(s-1)^2 + 1^2 } =  \dfrac {1 }{(s-1)^2 + 1 } = \dfrac{1}{s^2-2 s+2}$$

Do you now understand why you are having issues? In one case, we are finding the Laplace Transform  of the **convolution** of two functions and in the other, we are finding the Laplace Transform of the **produc**t of two functions and these are different things.

Comment: no, sorry not quite following where to proceed.

Comment: I cleaned up the result to hopefully makes things clearer.

Comment: How do we conclude the last result from convolution results?

Comment: How can we use the same to calculate $\displaystyle \mathcal{L} (t\, \sin t)$

Comment: Perhaps review these notes and the example starting on page 3: http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jav/soton/HELM/workbooks/workbook_20/20_5_convolution_thm.pdf and this video https://cosmolearning.org/video-lectures/example-convolution-theorem-ftt-gtsint/

Answer (score 1):

On a hunch that may be OP was confused about $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(e^t \sin t)\:$ and $\:\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(e^t * \sin t)$.

The convolution operation $\:\displaystyle e^t * \sin t \:$ is not same as multiplication operation $\displaystyle e^t \sin t\:$.

The convolution $\: f * g \:$ has a definition of its own, in the form of an integral:

$$f * g = \int_0^t f(t)g(t-\tau) d \tau$$
If $\:f = e^t \:$ and $\:g = \sin t \:$ then 
\begin{align}
fg &= e^t \sin t  \qquad \qquad \text{(Multiplication)}\\
f*g &= \frac{1}{2}(e^t + \sin t - \cos t) \qquad \text{(Convolution)}
\end{align}
Above two functions $fg$ and $f*g$ are generated from the same set, but they are entirely different functions now.

This answers your question as to why $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(e^t \sin t)\:$ is different from $\:\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(e^t * \sin t)$.

A property of convolution is: $\quad\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(e^t * \sin t) = \mathcal{L}(e^t) \mathcal{L}(\sin t)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{s-1} \frac{1}{s^2-1}$.

RHS is ordinary multiplication and no "$*$". Note that same does not hold for multiplication, i.e. $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(e^t \sin t) \neq \mathcal{L}(e^t) \mathcal{L}(\sin t)$. You have to use Integration or Translation theorem to calculate $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(e^t \sin t) $

Comment: @Moo: I understand it now. Thanks.